# Page reload causes Vuex getter to return undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

Using Vue.js (Vuetify for FE).

A page reload causes the getter in Vuex to fail with pulling required data from the store. The getter returns undefined. The code can be found on GitHub at: https://github.com/tineich/timmyskittys/tree/master/src

Please see the full details on this issue at timmyskittys.netlify.com/stage1. This page has complete info on the issue and instructions on how to view the issue.

Note, there is mention of www.timmyskittys.com in the issue description. This is the main site. timmyskittys.netlify.com is my test site. So, they are the same for all intents and purposes. But, my demo of this issue is at the Netlify site.

Comment: You are losing the store state when you reload the page. Possible solutions: attempt to get one of the vuex persistence modules to work again, modify your store getters and mutations to save/pull from local storage, add a null check in your getter to refetch the data, or try using a navigation guard `beforeRouteEnter` to do a null check and refetch data if null.

Answer (score 0):

I read the complete issue in the website you mentioned. It's a generic case.

Say, for cat details page url:  `www.timmyskittys.com/stage2/:id`.

Now in Per-Route Guard `beforeEnter()` you can set the `cat-id` in store. Then from your component call the api using the `cat-id` (read from getters)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and taking the time to look at my issue. I have been beating my head for months now because of this issue. I did try the beforeEnter(), but yields the same issue. I'll certainly give it another try. Would you mind providing more details on your suggestion? The store and components code can be found on github: https://github.com/tineich/timmyskittys/tree/master/src

Comment: Hi Sajib. Yes, I finally was able to solve. The issue was I was sourcing my data and pulling it into Vuex inside a component that was part of <router-view>. I had to move my call of the action that calls the mutation into App.vue (which puts it outside of <router-view>). Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue:

I had to move the call of the action which calls the mutation that loads the .json file (dbdata.json) into a computed() within App.vue. This was originally done in Stage1.vue.

Thanks all for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my "fix" if it can be called that was to make a timer, so to give the store time to get things right, like so:

```
<v-treeview
    :items="items"
    :load-children="setChildren"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

const pause = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      children: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('app', ['services']),
    items () {
      return [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Services',
        children: this.children
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async setChildren () {
      await pause(1000)

      this.children.push(...this.services)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Even though this is far from ideal, it works.